# On any Stack Exchange site, links included in the Help Center lead to help pages on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center

On any Stack Exchange site (for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)), the help page about *Help Center > Answering > How to reference material written by others* (….stackexchange.com/help/referencing) shows a short list including two links:

> - Provide a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to the original page or answer
> - [Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

On any site, both links lead to help pages on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes, respectively).

However, since the corresponding help pages are also available on each individual Stack Exchange site (for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)), the links should point to the respective site instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason that particular page had the domains explicitly as part of the links. I looked at some various other help pages and those ones didn't exhibit the same problem, but these ones have been fixed.

Let us know if you find other pages which have incorrect links like this.